# Check if 2 BSTs have the same in-order traversal simultaneously using recursion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, graph, tree

I am looking at this problem [discussed on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lbwfkCfNQ4&t=9s):

> Given two binary trees, determine whether they have the same inorder traversal:
>
> ```
>       Tree 1              Tree 2
>
>          5                   3
>        /   \               /   \ 
>       3     7             1     6
>      /     /                   / \
>     1     6                   5   7
>
>    [1,3,5,6,7]           [1,3,5,6,7]
> ```

I wanted to know how to solve this problem by doing a simultaneous in-order traversal of both trees using only recursion. I know people alluded to it in the comment section but I assume they mean iteratively.

My first thought was to use 1 function and pass in 2 lists to hold the values of the trees, and then compare them in the parent function. But this seems to work on only trees that have the same height (I think).

```
def dual_inorder_traversal(self, p, q, pn = [], qn = []):
    if not p and not q: return
    if not q: pn.append(p.val)
    if not p: qn.append(q.val)
    if p and q:
        self.dualInorder(p.left, q.left)
        pn.append(p.val)
        qn.append(q.val)
        self.dualInorder(p.right, q.right)
    return pn, qn
```

I then tried mutual recursion in which I have two functions, one that recurses tree1 and another that recurses tree2 and have them call each other. My idea was that we could append the root in the tree1 function when we visit it, and then then pop it from the list and compare when we visit the root in the tree2 function. Not even going to post what I tried because it didn't work at all lol. Also not even sure if mutual recursion is even possible in this case.

Comment: `this seems to work on only trees that have the same height` correct in that it wouldn't work on trees with different height, but identical in-order sequence of node labels. Please ask an *explicit* question in the post body. The answer may be: *depends* - on mechanisms available, for one thing. Python sports at least one form of *coroutines*: [generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/#motivation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that your first attempt to recurse through both trees in a single recursive function is difficult to do when the trees have different shapes: you may need to recur deeper in one tree, while in the other you are stuck at a leaf. This means you need to maintain lists to collect values (as can be seen in your code).

But storing values in lists is really defeating the purpose of the challenge. You might then as well collect all values in two lists and compare the lists, or collect the values of one tree in one list and compare against that list while making the traversal in the other (as is done in the video you linked to). Yet, it should not be necessary to use that much space for the job.

The idea to have two separate traversals going on in tandem is more promising. It becomes really easy when you make the traversal function a *generator*. This way that function stops running whenever the next value is found, giving you the opportunity to proceed in the other traversal also with one step.

Here is an `inorder` generator you could define in the `Node` class:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def inorder(self):
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left.inorder()
        yield self.value
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right.inorder()
```

Now it is a matter of iterating through `p.inorder()` and `q.inorder()` in tandem. You can write this with a loop, but `itertools` has a very usefull `zip_longest` function for that purpose:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def same_inorder(p, q):
    return all(v1 == v2 for v1, v2 in zip_longest(p.inorder(), q.inorder()))
```

There is a boundary case when the trees have a different number of nodes, but their inorder traversal is the same until the smaller tree is fully iterated. Then `zip_longest` will fill up the gap and produce `None` values to compare with. So as long as the tree nodes do not have `None` as value, that is fine. If however you expect nodes to have `None` values (quite odd), then use a different filler value. For instance `nan` could be an option:

```
 zip_longest(p.inorder(), q.inorder(), fillvalue=float("nan"))
```

As a demo, let's take these two trees:

```
             5                   3
           /   \               /   \ 
          3     7             1     6
         /     /                   / \
        1     6                   5   7
```

Then you can create and compare their inorder traversals as follows:

```py
tree1 = Node(5,
    Node(3,
        Node(1)
    ), Node(7,
        Node(6)
    )
)

tree2 = Node(3,
    Node(1),
    Node(6,
        Node(5),
        Node(7)
    )
)

print(same_inorder(tree1, tree2))  # True
```

### Time and Space use

Let's define  as the number of nodes in the first tree and  as the number of nodes in the second tree.

- Runtime complexity = O(+)
- Average, auxiliary space complexity = O(log() + log())

The auxiliary space excludes the space already used by the input, which is  O(+). On top of this we need to use the stack during the recursion. On average that will be O(log() + log())

Comment: Wow, I forgot about generators, solution is perfect! Thank you